# Google analytics e-commerce data is blank

Tags: google-analytics

In google analytics admin, I've chosen `'objectives' -> 'payment made'` and defined the objective detail as `"regular expression"` and entered `'/step-4.html'` in the text box.

This is because and the end of my shopping cart the URL contains somewhere 'step-4.html' in it.

However, when analysing the reports, this objective is never met although there were some sales and test orders that reached this page.

Also, in admin, I've activated the e-commerce definitions but my conversions are always zero in the reports.

Why is this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are talking about a destination goal, so if your page ends in "/step-4.html" with anything else in front, then it should be:

```
.*\/step-4\.html$
```

If that string is somewhere else in the URL (and not at the very end), then you just have to replace the `$` with `.*`.

(Note that I've escaped forward slashes and dots.)

You should be able to see conversions in Real-Time reports if all is working.